# How to get last created ID from SQL database using Linq-to-SQL / Linq-to-Entities (MVC)

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want to get the last entry into the database, I usually used `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in ado.net to get the last created id, but how to achieve that in Linq-to-SQL or Linq-to-Entities?

For instance I need to get the last added `bookingID` from the `booking` table whose `userID=xxxx`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both linq-to-sql and EF do this automatically. You just need to insert an object, save/submit changes and check id property in your object. If correctly configured it should be filled with scope identity.

- In case of EF the property must be configured with `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity`
- In case of Linq-to-Sql the property must be configured with `IsDbGenerated = true` (Auto Generated Value in dbml designer)